# Add amount to variable foreach row

Tags: php, mysql

I am trynna calculate total earnings, but it's returning funky values. And i don't know why?

My code:

```
        $getpayments = $odb->prepare("SELECT * FROM payments");
        $getpayments->execute();

        $amount = 0;
        while($row = $getpayments->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
            $price = $row['total_requests'];

            $amount += $price;
        }

        if($getpayments)
        {
        return $amount;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
```

There is 7 rows in database, and each value in paid amount is 5 but it's returning 30 in amount when it should be 35? What's wrong with the code? I also tried a foreach loop but then it was 22 instead of 30, very strange.

Comment: Can you show the payments table, `total_requests` looks and odd column name for a paid amount.

Answer (score 0):

your code is doing extra processing by loop over, you may do direct instead , I am not sure it solve your logical issue.

```
$getpayments = $odb->prepare("SELECT SUM(total_requests) FROM payments");
$getpayments->execute();
$getpayments->bind_result($amount);
$getpayments->fetch();
return $amount;
```